# Android Keyboard : managing Keyboard appearance / disappearance inside fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard, focus, fragment

I have an app that contains at some point a FragmentActivity. This FragmentActivity contains some Fragments (FragmentA, FragmentB, etc). On each of these fragments, there are one or more EditText.

I'm trying to handle the keyboard properly. I want to make the Keyboard appear or disappear whenever I want.

For Example, When the FragmentA is created, I want to open the keyboard on an EditText. Then, three options possible for the user :

1. He clicks on a button that goes to the next fragment
2. He clicks on the Action Send of the Keyboard(that does nothing (on purpose) but close the keyboard normally) and then he can click on the button from the view
3. He clicks on the back button of the phone. In this case, it closes the keyboard and then he can click on the button form the view.

My problem is, whenever the user closes the keyboard by clicking on the back button of the phone, Android thinks that he doesn't want to see the keyboard ever in the activity. So when the FragmentB is created, I can't programmatically show the keyboard (Using InputManager btw) on a EditText from this Fragment.

Then, a second problem is when i click on the edittext to get the focus, in Android 4.x, the keyboard shows again, no problems, but with Android 2.x, it's impossible to have the keyboard shown again even if the focus is on the edittext ! It's killing me.
It appears that once the user has explicitly close the keyboard with the back button in one activity (even a fragment activity), you cannot show it again.

Does anyone have a solution ? Maybe playing with the flags in InputManager ? I didn't get all of them and what they do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Show keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
EditText view = getCurrentFocus();
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Hide keyboard:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Hope it helps ;)